# Rails - Indexing records based on their category

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, controller, actionview

My project is setup where each movie has many genres and each genre has many movies. So for instance a movie can have one or more genres of such categories: Action, Comedy, Drama. What I'd like to do is create views for each genre that list the movies that belong to them, similar to how the default index action is setup:

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :name
    has_many :genreships
    has_many :genres, through: :genreships

    extend FriendlyId
    friendly_id :name, use: :slugged
end

class Genreship < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :movie
    belongs_to :genre
end

class Genre < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :name
    has_many :genreships
    has_many :movies, through: :genreships

    extend FriendlyId
    friendly_id :name, use: :slugged
end
```

**Movies Controller**

```
def index
  @movies = Movie.all
end
```

**Movies Index View**

```
<% @movies.each do |movie| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

With each genre-based url looking something like this: `localhost:3000/comedy`

I realize that creating an index action for each and every genre wouldn't scale well so I'm wondering what would be the best solution to dynamically create these pages. I've done some research regarding to the topic but most of them have been geared towards creating *nested routes* where as I'm leaning more towards the Action View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need routes:

```
get '/:genre', to: 'movies#genre_movies'
```

Then your action will read:

```
def genre_movies
  @movies = Genre.find_by(name: params[:genre]).movies
  render 'index'
end
```

Comment: What would the view template for `genre_movies` look like? I see that you render the `index` view in your method but wouldn't that render every movie across all genres?

Comment: I also received a NilClass error: `undefined method 'movies' for nilClass`

Comment: @CarlEdwards - This means you have no such a gender stored in your database. How will the view look like depends on you - it will work as a regular index method, except that `@movies` variable is now filtered.

Comment: What's strange is that I'm able to query the genres and movies in my rails console as follows: `movie = Movie.first` `movie.genres` and it returns this: `#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Genre id: 1, name: "Comedy", slug: "", created_at: "2014-11-11 18:33:49", updated_at: "2014-11-11 18:33:49">]`. Its definitely there but for some reason not getting recognized.

Comment: Check genres capitalisation.

Comment: Like so? `movie.Genres`. Wouldn't this return an error regardless though?

Comment: No, when you pass `localhost:3000/comedy` it will fail to find a genre as you don't have such. You have `Comedy`, not `comedy`. It is probably the best practice to keep data like this al lower-case and capitalize it as needed.

Comment: That did the trick! Is there a way downcase these genres on the backend without necessarily affecting how they look within the views? I'm aware of downcasing them in a before action within `genre.rb` but if I were to reference it in a view it would be `comedy` yet again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64733/discussion-between-broisatse-and-carl-edwards).

Comment: Just a minor revision for future users: `'movies#genre_moview'` needs to be changed to `'movies#genre_movies'`

Comment: After playing around with this it seems that despite it running okay for that one genre route the rest of the site's routes break. For instance: `localhost:3000/movies`, `localhost:3000/genres`

Comment: @CarlEdwards - you need to move `get '/:genre'` to the very bottom of your routes.rb file - below all the resources.